# Query for EU universities from Wikidata times out

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Asking the Wikidata service for all universities works. But when restricted to only EU universities, [this query](https://w.wiki/ipY) times out.

```
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3918 ;
         wdt:P17 ?country.
   ?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458 .
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Any idea?

Strangely, using `FILTER EXISTS` is returns the result (although quite slow).

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?countryLabel ?country
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3918 ;
         wdt:P17 ?country.
FILTER EXISTS { ?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458 }
SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Here's a link to the [second query](https://w.wiki/iqd).

Comment: this maybe? `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?countryLabel ?country
WITH {
   select distinct ?item {?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q3918}
} AS %results 
WHERE {
  INCLUDE %results.
  ?item wdt:P17 ?country.?country wdt:P463 wd:Q458 .   
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

}`

Comment: https://w.wiki/is5